# Wcf Push Service in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-store-apps

I´m trying to implement a Wcf Duplex Service in my Windows Store Application. In my .NET WPF Application everything works fine. I use a NetTcpBinding.

Here is my Service Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="myNetTcpBinding" receiveTimeout="00:30:00">
      <reliableSession enabled="true" inactivityTimeout="24.20:31:23"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="CnS.Base.Services.MessageHub.MessageHubService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myNetTcpBinding" contract="CnS.Base.Services.MessageHub.IMessageHubService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress = "net.tcp://localhost:8655/MessageHubService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False" httpsGetEnabled="False"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

If i call a Method from the WCF Service i get a ActionNotSupportedException.I figured out that if i set

```
 <reliableSession enabled=false"/>
```

It works fine. But my Problem is now that the Wcf connection is closed to my Windows Store App and i can´t Push Messages to this client.
Does anyone know a workaround for this Problem?